# Laravel 4 returns blank page when using return withInput (file attached)

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

I have HTML form with contains text and file fields:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{url('control')}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ...
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="business_name" id="business_name"

 ...
 <label for="business_name">Brand Logo</label>
 {{Form::file('logo')}}
 {{{ $errors->first('logo') }}}
 </form>
```

I validate the input:

```
...
'logo' => 'image',
```

I return to the form `withInput` and `withErrors` if the `Validator` produces false:

```
 return Redirect::to('control')->withInput($inputs)->withErrors($validator->getMessageBag());
```

This works fine if no files are selected during the filling in process, I'm returned to the form `withInput` and `withErrors`

**But**

if I selected a file during the filling process and I submit with invalid input I'm returned `/control` which is completely **empty** this time.

**Edit**

After A comment recommendation I checked Laravel log:

```
[2013-12-23 17:05:17] production.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message    'Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed' in C:\wamp\www\*****\***\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Store.php:212
```

I can't seem to find away to solve it so far any recommendation is welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator)` ?

Comment: check your logs (Apache &/or Laravel's) for errors

Comment: @SheikhHeera just tried back() that also produces an empty page also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially had this in a comment, but unintentionally deleted it.  I'll repost it as an answer just in case someone else stumbles across this.

Pass `withInput()` without the `$inputs` parameter, like so:

`Redirect::to('control')->withInput();`

`withInput()` doesn't require parameters.

Comment: not passing withinput() parameters works perfectly. strange, will dig into the docs to find an explanation. Thank you

Comment: p.s your removed comment helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: I added the answer back in case anyone else stumbles across this.